# Is there a list of illegal Tor areas?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, legal

I just moved to Singapore and I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use the Tor browser (without a bridge) and run a relay (not an exit node). I realize that this question could be repeated for any jurisdiction in the world, so I'm wondering if there is a list of jurisdictions that consider Tor illegal in the world?

Answer (score 5):

To quote Roger Dingledine from many talks given about Tor:

"To our knowledge there isn't a country/place where Tor has been declared illegal."
(Not exactly his words throughout the years.)

To my knowledge, which is more limited than the input the TorProject gets, this is still the case.