# Is it illegal to use Tor and any encryption product in Russia?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, encryption, legal

I've read http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#ru but also [Is there a list of illegal Tor areas?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/is-there-a-list-of-illegal-tor-areas).

So I'm kind of confused, do you guys know anything about this matter?

Comment: I'd recommend asking in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/. Your question deals more with cryptography and politics in general, than with Tor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would'nt answer your question. I'll say my opinion:

- Any Radio jammer
- Any Tor node
- Any home brewed encryption

They start watching you.

---

One of the most famous forum for you to ask your question is [www.pgpru.com](https://www.pgpru.com/). There are couple of jurists who could answer you more broadly.

Comment: Thanks :) That's pretty awesome, do you know any similar website not written in Russian?

Comment: Not written in Russian about Russian legislation? I'm pretty sure, that this guys would answer you on English. Try also, https://crypto.stackexchange.com as Jens Kubieziel mention.